# Ethereum contract execution

Tags: solidity

If I write a Ethereum contract something like this (taken from https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html)

> pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
> contract SimpleStorage {
>
> ```
> uint storedData;
> function set(uint x) {
>     storedData = x;
> }
>
> function get() constant returns (uint) {
>     return storedData;
> } }
> ```

if someone called the "set" operation, would it be executed 30 time ( assuming 30 nodes are supporting blockchain, at that point in time). Appreciate confirmation one way or other.

( I know similary question is already been asked, though that is not very clear for me atleast, neither I am able to add comment to that question, hence creating new one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose someone sends a transaction, `set(10);`

Generally speaking, each miner will run the function to assess the result and possibly include it in a block.

After it's mined, each full node will run the function to assess the result.

At the end of this process, the nodes will be in agreement about their *independent conclusions* about the result of the transaction.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob, if I understand correctly field store data would be set to 10 in each full node. Effectively nodes are replicating the state, as they do with transaction. Am I getting this right here?

Comment: Exactly. Nodes are replicating the state by completing the computations themselves. As a developer (Solidity) it's usually sufficient to understand this as one computation; backed by a very fault-tolerant platform with considerable redundancy.

Comment: @user1687711 Thanks for the "accept".